# "As time goes by" vs. "As time has gone by"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I wonder what the difference between the two phrases given in the title is. For example:

> As time goes by, people have learned that the earth is not the center of the universe.
>
> As time has gone by, people no longer think the earth is the center of the universe.
>
> As time goes by, people have no longer thought that the earth is the center of the universe.
>
> As time has gone by, people think the earth is not the center of the universe.

Here is my confusion:

- Are both phrases correct? (present simple vs. present perfect)
- What's the correct combination for "As time goes by"/"As time has gone by", the existence of "no longer" (for things that has changed), and whether the following sentence uses a simple tense or a perfect tense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start a sentence with a clause based on **as time goes by**, the second clause describes what happens as the time is passing, and so it has to be of the same tense as the **as time goes by** clause. You can't, for example, use present simple in the first clause and present perfect in the second clause.

We use the **simple present** to talk about general truths: things that were true in the past, are true now and always will be true.

> As time goes by, we realise that nothing in life is certain, apart from death.

We use **present perfect** to talk about things that have taken place over a period of time and are still happening, or things that happened in the past  and have some lasting effect (for example making a reservation).

> As time has gone by, people have become more dependent on their phones.

Realising that the earth is not the centre of the universe is something that happened a long time ago: it is no longer an issue. It therefore makes more sense to use **past simple**. For past simple, we want a verb that expresses an event rather than a state, so **learn** works better than **think**:

> As time went by, people learned that the Earth is not the center of the universe.

Two other comments about your sentences. First, **people** is plural, so it's **people think**, not **people thinks**. Second, if we want to talk about the planet we live on, we ususally (but not always) use the definite article **the earth**. The capital letter on Earth is optional.

Comment: My understanding went wrong.

Comment: Is it all clear now?

Comment: Yup. Waiting for some more time before accepting this one.

Comment: Always good to wait and see whether somebody can produce a better answer :-).